# How to pass single data from child to parent component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new at React native and I'm trying to pass a data(which is user current location) from child component to a parent component.

Parent

```
const MapScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [changeMapView, setChangeMapView] = useState('standard');
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState('#ffffff');
  const [iconColor, setIconColor] = useState('purple');
  
  let currentPosition; // varibale that I have declared 

  console.log('current position in mapscreen.js', currentPosition)

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapLook>
        <Map mapType={changeMapView} currentPosition={currentPosition} />
      </MapLook>

      <ButtonView>
        <SatelitViewPanel
          changeMapView={changeMapView}
          setChangeMapView={setChangeMapView}
        />

        <LocationViewPanel 
        currentPosition={currentPosition}
        />
      </ButtonView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default MapScreen;
```

Child

```
const Map = (props, currentPosition) => {

  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState({
    longitude: 12.5683,
    latitude: 55.6761
  });

  const getRegionForType = (type) => {
    const regionData = {
      longitude: mapRegion.longitude,
      latitude: mapRegion.latitude
    };
    return regionData;
  }
  
  const getMapRegion = () => getRegionForType('map');
  
  currentPosition = getMapRegion() // geting the current position 
  console.log(currentPosition) // in the console it shows the current position

  const getMarkerCoords = () => getRegionForType('marker');
  
  const setRegionForLocation = (location)=> {
    let coords = location.coords;
    let longitude = coords.longitude;
    let latitude = coords.latitude;

    if(mapRegion.longitude === longitude && mapRegion.latitude === latitude)
    return;

    setMapRegion({longitude, latitude, longitudeDelta, latitudeDelta});
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
      >
        {mapRegion != null && (
          <Marker coordinate={getMarkerCoords()}>
            <Image source={require('../../assets/marker.png')} style={{ height: 90, width: 90 }} />
          </Marker>
        )}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Map;
```

When I `console.log(currentPostion)` in the parent component, it outputs`undefined`.
I tried to do it with hook state, but it showed that `setState` is not a function

How can I pass the data from child to parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps your problem.

```
const Map = ({currentPosition, ...props}) => {  /// need to change props in this type.

  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState({
    longitude: 12.5683,
    latitude: 55.6761
  });

  const getRegionForType = (type) => {
    const regionData = {
      longitude: mapRegion.longitude,
      latitude: mapRegion.latitude
    };
    return regionData;
  }
  
  const getMapRegion = () => getRegionForType('map');
  
  currentPosition = getMapRegion() // geting the current position 
  console.log(currentPosition) // in the console it shows the current position

  const getMarkerCoords = () => getRegionForType('marker');
  
  const setRegionForLocation = (location)=> {
    let coords = location.coords;
    let longitude = coords.longitude;
    let latitude = coords.latitude;

    if(mapRegion.longitude === longitude && mapRegion.latitude === latitude)
    return;

    setMapRegion({longitude, latitude, longitudeDelta, latitudeDelta});
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
      >
        {mapRegion != null && (
          <Marker coordinate={getMarkerCoords()}>
            <Image source={require('../../assets/marker.png')} style={{ height: 90, width: 90 }} />
          </Marker>
        )}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1):

You decalre your useState, ex:

```
const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState();
```

And pass its hooks to child components:

```
 <LocationViewPanel 
    currentPosition={currentPosition} setCurrentPosition={setCurrentPosition}
    />
```

And finally, set position by using passed hook:

```
setCurrentPosition(getMapRegion());
```

So, it will work,

Comment: passed props, not hook. but yes this works

Comment: On setCurrentPosition(getMapRegion()), I get is not a function and after that setCurrentPosition is undefined.